# 29 CSV File concatenation in Python

Tags: python

I’m trying to write a code for file concatenation.
1. I have 29 files of different names in a directory. Each file name looks like “XXX- ‘Name of Indian State’-2010-11. csv
As there are 29 states, the file name changes in the middle term for each.

Each file has a header row which has like 5 columns( 5 sets of years say 2007-08,2008-09, 2009-10 etc.,) and there are 30 rows overall each having a common row index across all the files.

My objective is to create a dataframe concatening the 4th column of each of these data sets 
For example say my df should look like( with 29 columns and 30 rows)
                    AP_2010-11    Gujarat_2010-11 ......
Row Index I   Value 1           Value 2 .......

Where AP, Gujarat etc., are few of the Indian States

Would be great if someone can respond really soon and sort my problem

Comment: Look into the `csv` library for processing the actual document, and after that look into `pandas`, which excels at data manipulation like you seem to want to do here

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

I havent checked it for bugs but this is roughly how it should work:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

dirlist = os.listdir()
csvs = [file for file in dirlist if "csv" in file]
alldata = pd.DataFrame()
for myfile in csvs:
    actual_file_as_df = pd.read_csv(myfile)
    alldata = pd.concat([alldata,actual_file_as_df])
output = alldata.iloc[:,3]
```